# No se puede acceder al sitio web Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Al intentar descargar un documento a través de un formulario me sale este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He verificado la ruta y existe y todo aparenta estar bien.

```
   /* Seccion de Registro */
Route::get('/reportes', 'ReporteController@index')->name('reportes.index')->middleware('can:reportes.index');
Route::post('/reportes606', 'ReporteController@descargar_606')->name('reportes.606');
Route::post('/reportes607', 'ReporteController@descargar_607')->name('reportes.607');
Route::post('/reportes608', 'ReporteController@descargar_608')->name('reportes.608');
Route::post('/reportesit1', 'ReporteController@descargar_it1')->name('reportes.it1');
```

He borrado las cookies y la cache del navegador y aun así sigue el problema.

Comment: El sitio está en localhost? o alojado en un servidor en la web? tienes en `true`: `APP_DEBUG` en el archivo `.env`? el te muestra más detalle del error, en caso de que lo tengas en `false` cambialo a `true` y envía el error que te arroja para ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Cuál error? Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Puedes añadir lo que haga falta haciendo clic en [edit]. Saludos

Comment: El sitio esta en localhost y funcionaba todo perfectamente, pero le cambie la el url a la ruta agraguegandole 606, 607....

Comment: ¿Pero si accedes a la url base http://inder.test funciona?

Comment: Si todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: Son rutas POST, no puedes acceder poniendo esa url en el navegador, debes enviar una petición post a esas rutas o cambiarles el método a GET.

Comment: Envie una petición post de un formulario.por eso las rutas son tipo post. Me estaban funcionando de esa manera.

Comment: Ya se cual fue el error. Mi error estaba en un un print() que estaba tratando de imprimir dos variables como una array. Ya esta solucionado. Gracias